# Mybatis: how to check if a row exists and return a boolean?

Tags: mysql, mybatis

The database is MySQL. The code should look like as below:

```
public interface UserMapper {
    @Select("....")
    boolean checkUserExists(@Param("email") String email);
}
```

Is it possible, and how to write the SELECT SQL? (can Exists be used?)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can use EXISTS

```
@Select("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE email=#{email})")
boolean checkUserExists(@Param("email") String email);
```

Note that "SELECT 1" is there for a reason, you don't need to select any actual columns

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution:

```
public interface UserMapper {
    @Select("SELECT " 
           + " CASE WHEN Count(email)>0 THEN 1 " 
           + " ELSE 0 END Result "
           + " FROM TUser "
           +"  WHERE email=#{email}")
    boolean checkUserExists(@Param("email") String email);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For mybatis to recognize true or false, this select should return 0 or 1, for this we use COALESCE.
The query returns the value 1 and when it returns null the coalesce returns 0.
Make sure your query returns only one record.

```
public interface UserMapper {
    @Select("SELECT COALESCE ((SELECT 1 FROM TUser WHERE email=#{email}), 0) ")
    boolean checkUserExists(@Param("email") String email);
}
```

Comment: Note that allowing a user to create the statement instead of defining it in a MySQL procedure to validate the data means it might be possible to do Injection Attacks on the database.

Answer (score 0):

here is:

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
    WHERE 
        TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a List of User in Mapper and check if the size of List is larger than 0.

Answer (score 0):

> @Select("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM my_table WHERE email=#{email})")
> boolean checkUserExists(@Param("email") String email);

it is unnecessary to use FUNC "EXSITS(...)".

Usually, i like that.

```
@Select("select 1 from my_table where email = #{email} limit 1")
Optional<Boolean> checkUserExists(@Param("email") String email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to answer by Zach, for DB2 you have to use CASE. The code is old usingmapper.xml file, not annotations.

```
<select id="isBenefitPatternAReviewGroup" resultType="boolean">

SELECT   Distinct
                CASE
                WHEN VAL > 0 THEN 'true'
                ELSE 'false'
                END
        FROM (
            SELECT  count(*) AS VAL
            FROM table_user 
            WHERE email=#{email}
;

</select>
```